# Find all deprecated code in an Ionic 4, Angular 7 project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code

I have an Ionic 4 / Cordova / Angular 7 project that I'm looking to upgrade to Ionic 5 and Angular 10. I'm aware that it's best to upgrade Angular one version at a time.

When I run my app, I can see messages in the debug output like:

```
[DEPRECATED][CSS] Ionic CSS attributes are deprecated.
Replace:
'<ion-label text-capitalize>'

With:
'<ion-label class="ion-text-capitalize">'
```

I'd like to find all of these (and any other deprecation messages) without having to navigate to every page of my app and watch the output. I figured there must be a build option or a tool to find and list all these deprecations but I can't for the life of me find one. I thought VS Code or Intellij (phpstorm) might show warnings, but no.

Is there something that can find all the deprecated code in one go?

Comment: As of now, there is no such utility that would find the deprecated code. You will have to go through the migration guide and look at breaking changes https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/master/BREAKING.md#version-5x

Comment: @PankajSati I thought that might be the case. Thanks for the confirmation and the link.

Comment: Try `ng lint` Linting should throw deprecation warning